# How do I bookmark a page in Google Books?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google, google-apps, epub

Google Books has a feature whereby you can bookmark a page by tapping any corner of any page of a book you're reading. However, I was unable to do this. Could someone please provide some help as to what I might be doing wrong, perhaps with a few images illustrating what should be happening in the user interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifically tap the top right corner to add a bookmark. Also, be sure to only tap once. A double tap will result in a zoom.

Alternatively, you can swipe down from the top of the screen, tap the three dot menu, and select "Add bookmark."